# Como obter o resultado da soma de dois valores do tipo float ao clicar num input?

Tags: javascript, html5

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function somarValores(){
        var s1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
        var s2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
        var s3 = parseInt(s1) + parseInt(s2);
        return s3;
    }
</script>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Cálculo do salário</legend>
    <label>Valor 1:</label>
    <input id="s1" type="text"/>
    <label>Valor 2: </label>
    <input id="s2" type="text"/>

    <label>Resultado: </label>
    <input id="resultado" onclick="somarValores()" type="text">

</fieldset>
```

Comment: você já fez praticamente todo o trabalho, só falta mostrar o resultado, colocar num campo, um alert, console.log? a *function* está retornando pra ninguém, no lugar de *return* tente mostrar o resultado. agora você colocou na pergunta *"tipo float"*, mas está usando `parseInt`, por que não `parseFloat`?

Answer (score 1):

Creio que assim resolva o seu problema, o seu código só faltou basicamente mandar escrever o valor do resultado no `input` referente ao resultado:

```js
function somarValores(){
        var s1 = document.getElementById("s1").value;
        var s2 = document.getElementById("s2").value;
        var s3 = parseInt(s1) + parseInt(s2);
        document.getElementById("resultado").value = s3;
    }
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Cálculo do salário</legend>
    <label>Valor 1:</label>
    <input id="s1" type="text"/><br>
    <label>Valor 2: </label>
    <input id="s2" type="text"/><br>

    <label>Resultado</label>
    <input id="resultado" onclick="somarValores()" type="text">

</fieldset>
```